# Why Public field in code behind isn't recognized?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to access a public field from .cs code behind file to .aspx file, but it returns an error:

"the name 'Name' does not exist in the current context".

I tried to do `<%=Naveh%>`, converting the field to a property, or making it static, but nothing worked. Only if I convert the project to a web application, it works, but my teacher wants it to be a web application project, so I can't change that.

Any help would be appreciated.

The code .cs behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class WebForm3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public String Name = "X";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

The .aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm3.aspx.cs" Inherits="FreeMarketProject.MasterPage.WebForm3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <%=Name %>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if `FreeMarketProject.MasterPage` is not the default namespace of the project, then everything in the .cs file should be wrapped in `namespace FreeMarketProject.MasterPage { }`

Comment: or should it not rather be `FreeMarketProject.WebForm3` instead of `FreeMarketProject.MasterPage.WebForm3` in the `Inherits` attribute?

Comment: I tried both and rebuilt the project, still the same @dlatikay

Comment: Just being picky, but there is no such thing as a "public variable". Do you mean "public class"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way by doing this:

**Code Behind:**

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public String Name = "X";
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected String Getname()
        {
            return Name.ToString();
        }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
       document.getElementById("idlabel").innerHTML = '<%= Getname().ToString() %>';
    })

</script>



 <div>
        <asp:Label ID="idlabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
  </div>
```

Comment: If `Name` cannot be accessed and it is `public` then clearly the aspx page is not tied to the right code behind. Therefore, your solution will not work either because all you did is to put it inside a method. Plus whats the point of calling `ToString()` on a `string`?

Comment: What do you mean `Name cannot be Accessed` @CodingYoshi. I'm just giving this solution of what he posted. All i knew is just helping him/her.

Comment: @CodingYoshi if you have any idea then we are free to help some and post.

Comment: don't get it either... ASP.NET does not require a member to be a method or property, it can read plain fields as well. if they're in scope and visible of course. I think the javascript/ready roundtrip would complicate things in this case, the <% ... %> injections do not depend on the readystate of the client-side document, they are substituted into the markup before the page is sent to the client.